# tabular navigation of information using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

i am trying to write my own tabular navigation for some information about a product. I have written this using my own knowledge of jquery and css however i am concerned that it is very bulky when it doesnt need to be? is there a way to check for all clicks? or just a better way of doing this 
example :http://jsfiddle.net/KrR3H/1/

```
$('div#tab1').click(function(){
    $('div#infoArea').html('example product info');
    $('#infoTab1').css({'border-bottom-right-radius' : '0px', 'border-bottom-left-radius' : '0px'});
    $('#infoTab2').css({'border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px', 'border-bottom-left-radius' : '5px'});
    $('#infoTab3').css({'border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px', 'border-bottom-left-radius' : '5px'});
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest:

```
var contents = {
    'tab1' : 'Description stuff',
    'tab2' : 'Technical jiggery-pokery',
    'tab3' : 'Reviews'
};
$('#tabContainer div[id]').click(function(){
    var self = this;
    $('#infoArea').html(contents[self.id]);
    $(self).css({
        'border-bottom-right-radius' : '0px',
        'border-bottom-left-radius' : '0px'
    }).siblings().css({
        'border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px',
        'border-bottom-left-radius' : '5px'
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KrR3H/2/).

Having offered the above, I'd prefer to *not* directly manipulate the CSS, and would rather use `addClass()`/`removeClass()` to achieve the same effects:

```
var contents = {
    'tab1' : 'Description stuff',
    'tab2' : 'Technical jiggery-pokery',
    'tab3' : 'Reviews'
};
$('#tabContainer div[id]').click(function(){
    var self = this;
    $('#infoArea').html(contents[self.id]);
    $(self).addClass('tabSelected').siblings().removeClass('tabSelected');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KrR3H/3/).

Note this latter version required some corrections of your CSS, you originally had:

```
.infoTab1 {
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
```

But, as `infoTab` is an `id` the selector is prefixed with a `#` not a period (`.`), to give:

```
#infoTab1 {
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
```

Also the selector for your `:hover` interaction was originally written as:

```
.infoTab a:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

This selector, though, was looking for an `a` that was `:hover`-ed within an element with the class of `infoTab`; when the element that was *being* hovered had that class, so the selector had to be re-written as:

```
a.infoTab:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: Thank you for a better solution however the code on js fiddle is not working ?

Comment: In what *way* is it 'not working'? What is it *not* doing that it *should*? I ask because it's doing what I *think* it should be.